# Unable to boot linux due to removing the filesystem package

Tags: linux, filesystems, fedora, rpm, yum

In my fedora x64 system I accidently did removed the "filesystem" package while I was root , by executing this command :

> **rpm -e filesystem --nodeps**

instead of doing this :

> **yum update filesystem**

and unfortunatly the command executed normally and the "filesystem" package was deleted totally .

now the system is refusing to boot up showing this message :

> **systemd[1] : Failed to execute /bin/sh , giving up : No such file or directory**

Now I can't do anything to fix it so any solutions are welcome, because I don't want to reinstall the system .

I am running an ***x64 Fedora 18 linux*** on an ***intel i3*** processor.

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) because it is not about programming or software development. You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same beast on Fedora 19, after 3 hours I found a quite straight forward solution, what I did was:

1. Boot from Fedora-Live USB-stick of the same version installed
2. Mounted root into a local directory (btrfs): `mount -o subvol=/root /dev/sda3 /mnt`
3. Downloaded the filesystem package, telling yum it's working and base-directory are at my mountpoint: `yum -c /mnt/etc/yum.conf --installroot=/mnt --downloadonly --downloaddir=/~ install filesystem`
4. Since the package `filesystem.x.x.x.rpm` was gloriously removed by the `rpm -e filesystem --nodeps` command already, I installed the downloaded filesystem.rpm - at least I thought so. Turned out I had to force rpm because some other package from Google-Earth was blocking my command:
   `rpm -Uvh --root=/mnt ~/filesytem.x.x.x.rpm --force`
5. Finally I edited `/etc/selinux/config`, I turned it off:
   `SELINUX=disabled`

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the drive out, install it in another system mount it as a secondary drive, and fool around with RPM to install the package in the specified path.

Bear in mind you'll need to manually check all your dependencies are installed too, and that you're building the correct version for Fedora 18.

I guess there might be other ways to do this too, but as long as you have another system you can connect the drive to, this might be the least effort.

Answer (score 0):

I'd boot your broken system off a rescue disk on DVD, CD, USB or what have you. My experience was with [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html) (a few years back), it was regarded as the best. However, if you don't have that, google "fedora rescue" and download that. See if that can read your hard drive, perhaps allowing you to avoid losing files of value that you had on old system, copy out to some removable media. Or, it may actually diagnose your situation and suggest fixing it for you.

Otherwise, I suspect the least-effort path back to a working system will be to install linux from scratch. The "filesystem" is not a separate package, it pretty much **is** the linux installation. The kernel is still present and booting, but everything else is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for the ISO mounted it extracted the rpm package filesystem-3.2-10.fc19.x86_64.rpm. I then looked for a live cd, boot into and mounted my former working partition and then run
rpm2cpio /root/filesystem-3.2-10.fc19.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv